# Quasar Framework Animation

Tags: css, typescript, animation, css-animations, quasar-framework

I've been working with Quasar Framework for a bit now, and I'm trying to implement some animations (i.e. a card flipping around to show editing options), but I don't think I quite understand how to implement it, or how animations work with Quasar's Framework.

Here's the indexPage.vue code (that's all you need to put in a general quasar project to see the page)

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md row justify-around items-start q-gutter-md">
    <q-intersection
      v-for="(card, index) in cards"
      :key="index"
      once
      transition="flip-right"
    >
      <transition-group class="my-card" tag="q-card">
        <q-card
          class="my-card"
          :class="{ flip: isFlipped }"
          v-show="!isFlipped"
        >
          <div class="card-bar">
            <q-item-section
              class="bar"
              :style="{ backgroundColor: card.color }"
            >
              <q-avatar
                color="red"
                size="7.5em"
                class="card-avatar"
                @click="animateCard"
                label="Flip Card"
              >
                <q-icon name="account_circle" size="lg" />
              </q-avatar>
            </q-item-section>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <q-item class="q-pb-xs card-name">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label class="text-weight-bold text-h5">{{
                  card.title
                }}</q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
            <q-item class="card-location">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label class="q-mt-sm text-weight-medium text-h4">{{
                  card.location
                }}</q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item class="card-note">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label class="text-weight-regular text-caption">{{
                  card.note
                }}</q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item class="card-update">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label
                  class="text-weight-light text-caption text-italic"
                >
                  <q-icon name="circle" :color="card.active" />
                  {{ card.subhead }}</q-item-label
                >
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
          </div>
        </q-card>
      </transition-group>
      <transition-group>
        <q-card class="my-card" :class="{ flip: isFlipped }" v-show="isFlipped">
          <div class="card-bar">
            <q-item-section
              class="bar"
              :style="{ backgroundColor: card.color }"
            >
              <q-avatar
                color="red"
                size="7.5em"
                class="card-avatar"
                @click="animateCard"
                label="Flip Card"
              >
                <q-icon name="account_circle" size="lg" />
              </q-avatar>
            </q-item-section>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <q-item class="q-pb-xs card-name">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label class="text-weight-bold text-h5">
                  TEST TITLE
                </q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
            <q-item class="card-location">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label class="q-mt-sm text-weight-medium text-h4">
                  TEST LOCATION
                </q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item class="card-note">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label class="text-weight-regular text-caption">
                  TEST NOTE
                </q-item-label>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-item class="card-update">
              <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label
                  class="text-weight-light text-caption text-italic"
                >
                  <q-icon name="circle" :color="card.active" />
                  TEST UPDATE</q-item-label
                >
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
          </div>
        </q-card>
      </transition-group>
    </q-intersection>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Ref, defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

interface Card {
  active: string;
  title: string;
  location: string;
  note: string;
  subhead: string;
  color: string;
}

const allCards: Card[] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const badge = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var active = '';

  switch (badge) {
    case 0:
      active = 'red';
      break;
    case 1:
      active = 'yellow';
      break;
    case 2:
      active = 'green';
      break;
  }

  const color = `#${red.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}${green
    .toString(16)
    .padStart(2, '0')}${blue.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}`;

  allCards.push({
    active: active,
    title: 'Card ' + i + ' Name',
    location: 'Title ' + i,
    note: 'Summary Here',
    subhead: 'Online ' + i,
    color: color,
  });
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  data() {
    return {
      isFlipped: false,
    };
  },
  setup() {
    // Define a data property to store the card information
    const cards: Ref<Card[]> = ref(allCards);

    return {
      cards,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    animateCard() {
      const cardElement = document.querySelector('.q-card');

      // Ensure cardElement is not null before proceeding
      if (cardElement) {
        // Add flip-in class
        cardElement.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__flipInX');

        // Wait for the animation to complete and then remove flip-in class
        setTimeout(() => {
          cardElement.classList.remove('animate__flipInX');
        }, 1000); // Adjust the time based on your animation duration

        // Add flip-out class after a delay
        setTimeout(() => {
          cardElement.classList.add('animate__flipOutX');
        }, 1000); // Adjust the time based on your animation duration
      }
    },
  },
});
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.my-card
  width: 27em
  height: 14.0625em

  .bar
    width: 5.75em
    height: 14.0625em
    background-color: #ff0000 // Set the desired color for the vertical bar
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    border-top-left-radius: 0.3em
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.27em

  .card-avatar
    margin-left: 0.25em

  .card-content
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    height: 100%
    margin-left: 9.25em

    .card-location
      margin-top: 0
      padding-top: 0


  .card-note
    flex-grow: 1

  .card-update
    margin-top: auto
</style>
```

This is a relatively new project, and I'm not sure what the best practices are, so tip for that would be appreciated as well.

I've tried adding some animation classes and functions that I've seen around. Apparently Quasar has animate.css built in, although I haven't seen any evidence of that being true or not.